# No such DSL method 'rtServer' found among steps in Jenkins job for JFrog Artifactory Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am trying to run a Jenkins job to publish my `war` file to Artifactory.
I am using **Declarative Pipeline** syntax

```
// ... previous stages
stage('rtServer to Artifactory'){
        steps {
                rtServer (
                id: 'Artifactory-MC',
                url: 'http://my-artifactory-domain/artifactory',


                credentialsId: 'credentialsID',
                timeout = 100
            )
        }
    } 

... //rtUpload stages and post block
```

When I run the Jenkins job I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'rtServer' found among steps
```

Answer (score 1):

Declarative pipeline in Artifactory Plugin was introduced in version 3.0.0. Upgrade your plugin version if it is lower, preferably to the latest version.

As for the timeout setting, this is currently bugged. This [jira issue](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-1273) tracks the fix. The timeout has a default value of 300 if not explicitly set.